# Testing asynchronous functions doesn't work

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

last week I started learning TypeScript, coming from 4 years of programming experience in Java. Quite a bit of a change. Anyway, I've come across a problem I've been unable to solve for the past few hours.

I have a schema :

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
username : { type: String, required: true },
passwordHash : { type: String, required: true },
passwordSalt : { type: String, required: true },
email : { type: String, required: true },
emailVerified : { type: Boolean, default: false },
firstName : { type: String, required: true },
lastName : { type: String, required: true },
postUpvotes : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
postDownvotes : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
commentUpvotes : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
commentDownvotes : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
creationDate : { type: Date, default: Date.now }, };
```

Now in my tests I want to test my required fields, meaning testing at which point I can insert an object in my mongodb.

```
describe('Test required user fields', function(){
    const gandalfTheWizard = new Student();

    it('Test required username',  function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.username = 'cooolboy';

        return gandalfTheWizard.save().then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')),
            err => { return expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error) }
        );
    });

    it('Test required passwordHash', function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.passwordHash = 'tes1';

        return gandalfTheWizard.save().then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')),
            err => { return expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error) }
        );
    });

    it('Test required passwordSalt', function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.passwordSalt = 'tes2';

        return gandalfTheWizard.save().then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')),
            err => { return expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error) }
        );
    });

    it('Test required email', function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.email = 'tes3';

        return gandalfTheWizard.save().then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')),
            err => { return expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error) }
        );
    });

    it('Test required firstName', function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.firstName = 'tes4';

        return gandalfTheWizard.save().then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')),
            err => { return expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error) }
        );
    });

    it('Test required lastName - inserts correct object', function() {
        gandalfTheWizard.lastName = 'tes5';

       
        // i spent multiple hours trying to figure out why this exact test always fails on first time
        // i can not figure it out and i am kinda done trying to figure this out
        // insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms - is the underlying error
         this.timeout(50000);

        return gandalfTheWizard.save();
    });
});
```

I have a few other tests, in which I simply save an object, which passes:

```
it('Save Student in database', function () {
    Student.findOne({ firstName: 'Harry' }).then(result => {
        if (result != null) {
            expect(result).to.be.null;
        }
    });

    timeWizardHarry.save();

    Student.findOne().then(result => {
        if (result != null) {
            expect(result._id).to.exist;
            expect(result.username).to.equal(timeWizardHarry.username);
            expect(result.email).to.equal(timeWizardHarry.email);
        }
    });
});
```

So I'm kind of out of ideas and hope someone might help me with this whole thing.
Sorry If you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that I didn't actually connect to my database.
My tests were completely faulty and my setup of database aswell.
I forgot to use AWAIT and I had

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

which was not working.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

made it work.